# Android - Line when touching screen

Tags: android

Got a problem that I can't figure out what's causing it: wherever I **drag my cursor** in the app, **a line is drawn in yellow**. Once I drop the cursor, that line disappears.

Here's a screencap of the virtual device (it happens on the real devices as well):

http://resources.reament.com/screencaps/20120308_1246.png

As you can imagine, I would like to stop drawing any lines. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Alejandro.

Comment: That's interesting. I'd probably have to see the code to have any idea though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jesse, Houndshell's suggestion has solved it (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a GestureOverlayView.  It defaults gestures to visible, meaning it shows what you drew.  Grab it and call setGestureVisible(false).

Poke around in here, you can change the style to suit, or just hide it.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

Comment: Hounshell you are BIG. As you thought, I had an extra GestureOverlayView on my layout.
Thanks man.

Comment: I was messing with them recently, so I recognized the line ;-)